# create a subset of xmls files from an original xmls while keeping the same structure

Tags: c++, c, xml, libxml2

my question is I would like to create a subset of xmls files from an original xmls while keeping the same structure. You can say I would like to filter to have a subsets.

What's the best way to approach such a task and the most efficient way as I'm dealing with Medline database!

Answer (score 0):

A broad overview here.

1. Read the input xml file completely.
2. Decide at which level do you want to split the xml files. (e.g. level 3)
3. Decide the tags of interest. You can decide the tags in advance or provide some gui to the user to select which tags are required. You can also split the input file into many files containing all the tags of the input file.
4. Create the output files. e.g. upto level 3, the files are identical. At level 4 onwards you will have many files which are different.

e.g. if you have xml file like

```
<L1> .... 
    <L2> ...
        <L3> ....
           <L4a> .... </L4a>
           <L4b> .... </L4b>
           <L4c> .... </L4c>
        </L3>
    </L2>
</L1>
```

you can make 3 output files

```
<L1> .... 
    <L2> ...
        <L3> ....
           <L4a> .... </L4a>
        </L3>
    </L2>
</L1>    

<L1> .... 
    <L2> ...
        <L3> ....
           <L4b> .... </L4b>
        </L3>
    </L2>
</L1>
```

etc